# Bootstrap buttons will not move to the right

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have tried using `float-right` on my buttons as per the [Boostrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/)  but cannot get 3 of 4 buttons to move over to the right hand side of their containing div. What am I doing wrong?

[JSfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/157452/)

Note that I want the `Submit the form` button to stay where it is.

The code for those who cannot access the jsfiddle:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-1 px-3">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p>
            div above buttons
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">              
            <div class="btn-toolbar">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-1">Submit the form</button>
                <button type="button" id="SaveDraft" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1 float-right">Save Draft</button>
                <button type="button" id="RestoreDraft" class="btn btn-outline-warning mr-1 float-right" >Restore Draft</button>
                <button type="button" id="DeleteDraft" class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-1 float-right">Delete All Drafts</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried changing `btn-toolbar` to `btn-group`.

Comment: It looks like the .btn-toolbar is using flexbox to position the contents. Set add justify-content: flex-end to move the buttons across to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you problem because  `.btn-toolba` use `display: flex;` you can modify that behavior and targeting only this div by adding class and change the display value as below:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col-lg-12 {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
 .test.btn-toolbar{
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Parag Patel</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-1 px-3">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <p>
            div above buttons
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="test btn-toolbar ">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mr-1">Submit the form</button>
                <button type="button" id="SaveDraft" class="btn   mr-1 float-right">Save Draft</button>
                <button type="button" id="RestoreDraft" class="btn btn-outline-warning mr-1 float-right" >Restore Draft</button>
                <button type="button" id="DeleteDraft" class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-1 float-right">Delete All Drafts</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I've noticed that this seems to change the order of the buttons. Any idea why?

Comment: because it's cascading style so first item will be pushed to right then the following will be pushed after and if there is element already on the right then it will be placed after that element if you want to maintain the ordering you need wrap the buttons with span or div and assign only float-right to the span or div and remove float right from the buttons

Comment: Ah that makes sense. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row mt-1 px-3">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p>
        div above buttons
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12">              
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mr-1">Submit the form</button>
          <div style="margin-left: auto;">
            <button type="button" id="SaveDraft" class="btn btn-outline-primary mr-1 ">Save Draft</button>
            <button type="button" id="RestoreDraft" class="btn btn-outline-warning mr-1" >Restore Draft</button>
            <button type="button" id="DeleteDraft" class="btn btn-outline-danger mr-1 ">Delete All Drafts</button>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```